# All-Optical Magnetic Recording (Reversal through polarized pulses)

Tags: laser

Has any explanation or underlying cause been determined for this effect?  [Inverse Faraday effect, if I understand correctly.]
This seems like a fundamental property for which an arrow of causation may serve many purposes.  If others can direct me toward current theories or existing laws, I would appreciate it.

Encountered as a result of discovering author's speculation:  "Inverse Einstein–de Haas effect is responsible for this switching or a stimulated Raman-like coherent optical scattering process..."  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization_reversal_by_circularly_polarized_light